# New div append, removing first one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, ecmascript-6

We are showing an overlay message over a div, using the following code:

```
showOverlay({workItem, overlay}) {
        let $container = $(this._listView.getItemContainerByKey(workItem.backlogItemId)),
            $overlay = $(overlay);
        $container.append($overlay);
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.removeOverlay($container);
        }, this._options.delay);
    }
```

We want to show overlay on 2 items at the same time, but when we execute the above method for 2nd time, it removes to first overlay and only shows the second overlay.

$container is the div on which the overlay is to be shown
$overlay is the overlay which is to be appended.

you can check fiddle here: jsfiddle.net/AgileCockpit/sg3d8u9j

Comment: either remove `setTimeout(() => {..}` or increase it's time (`this._options.delay`).

Comment: @AlivetoDie...delay is already for 3 seconds..have checked with more as well but didn't work

Comment: can you please paste your html+script code here? so that some-one can check, or better to create a fiddle example. because with this much code no-one able to help you

Comment: @AlivetoDie... you can check it here https://jsfiddle.net/AgileCockpit/sg3d8u9j/

Comment: I have fixed it by creating the div to be appended everytime before appending.